Как задать темную тему для сайта на ASP.NET Core Razor Pages
нужно чтобы по умолчанию была темная тема при входе на сайт. (Razor Pages)

Если речь про стандартный шаблон, то там используется Bootstrap, который и отвечает за весь вид. Ну а темный режим у него появился не так давно, а именно, с версии 5.3.0. Собственно, чтобы была темная тема, вам надо сначала обновить сам Bootstrap (ПКМ по проекту - добавить - клиентская библиотека - пишете в поле Bootstrap  (должен подтянуть версию (на данный момент это 5.3.3), в поле "целевое расположение" указываете wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist (путь шаблона по умолчанию). Ну и далее, data-bs-theme="dark" к html тегу.

@EvgeniyZ, а почему в комментарии? :)

@NowhereMan Извините, возможно, это прозвучит грубо, но... Каждый человек делает свои выводы и принимает свои решения, включая такие, как "Отвечать на вопрос" или "Оставить комментарий". У каждого есть свои взгляды, принципы и идеалы. Если я решил написать комментарий вместо ответа, значит, я так хочу, не так ли? Или вы думаете, что за 8 лет я не научился пользоваться SO и промахнулся полем? К чему вот это? Если хотите конкретики, то это плохой вопрос, люди уже голосуют за его закрытие, ну а я не хочу подробно на него отвечать. Я против такого на SO и против такого в своем профиле.

@EvgeniyZ, понял, принял.  Имхо, вопрос не настолько некачественный, в частности у него пока что только один голос за закрытие.  Ваш комментарий мне показался вполне качественным ответом, извините, если что не так.

@NowhereMan Все мои комментарии я разрешаю копировать и делать на их основе свои ответы. Если есть желание - вперед. Моей задачей было лишь запустить студию, быстро найти решение, ну и написать комментарием свои наблюдения, не более. Я даже не уверен, что это то, что нужно и то, что это правильное решение) Попал - супер, нет - ну чтож... Ну а ответы я привык писать развернутые, подробные, качественные. В данном случае я дальше комментария идти не хочу.
